# How do I make the Awk work with Bash array variables in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

```
user=(`cat < usernameSorted.txt`)
for (( i=0; i<${#user[@]}; i++ ))
do
    `awk '$1 == "${user[$i]}"{print $NF}' process.txt > CMD$i.txt`
done
```

This is how I had coded for using user array elements as the awk specifier. How do I insert ${user[$i]} into the AWK command.

Comment: What do "work" and "limiting the range" mean? What are you trying to do? Your question will be closed unless you can clarify your problem and what you're expecting to happen and what isn't happening. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You're asking how to insert `${user[$i]}` into the AWK command, right? Please [edit] to clarify. For debugging help, it really helps to include a [mre] with example input, desired output, and actual output (like errors).

Comment: You have your `awk` script enclosed in single quotes; your shell variables will not be expanded inside the single quotes.  You'll probably need to use a variation on the theme of `awk -v user="${user[$i]}" '…program…' process.txt > "CMD$i.txt"` where you'll refer to `user` as an Awk variable set from `"${user[$i]}"` on the command line.

Comment: In general, to use awk (or sed, grep or any other filter) against shell variables, you will need to echo the variables, piped through the filter.  So, your awk line would look more like >> echo ${user[i]} | awk 'xxxxxxxx') (where xxxxxxxx is your awk command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680190/how-do-i-make-the-awk-work-in-shell-script#comment119628428_67680190), you have your Awk script enclosed in single quotes; your shell variables will not be expanded inside the single quotes.  On the whole, that's good; `$NF` is not one of your shell variables.

You'll probably need to use a variation on the theme of:

```
awk -v user="${user[$i]}" '$1 == user { print $NF }' process.txt > "CMD$i.txt"
```

where you refer to `user` as an Awk variable set from `"${user[$i]}"` on the command line.

---

There are a few other oddities in the script.  The `<` is not necessary with `cat`.  You could avoid the Bash array by using:

```
i=0
for user in $(cat usernameSorted.txt)
do
    awk -v user="$user" '$1 == user { print $NF }' process.txt > "CMD$i.txt"
    ((i++))
done
```

You do not want the back-ticks around the Awk command.  Fortunately, you redirect the standard output to a file so the string executed is empty, and nothing happens.